# Is there a huge sound quality difference if I use a monitor or an amp for my keyboard instead of using my logitech z906?

Tags: amplifiers, keyboard, speakers

I'm thinking of buying some monitors if it will boost the sound quality but I already have like a 400$ speaker for the computer.
Im wondering if it's worth or not for the investment

Comment: Are you talking about just playing at home, or for live performance? Are you experiencing any obvious problems with your Logitech system?

Comment: just playing at home. maybe in the future I do some live performance

Comment: A $400 speaker for computer? What is it? Lots of players don't pay that for stage use! (The two I use regularly cost me less than £50 each, and that includes amps!)  There's stage monitors and computer monitors - and a heck of a difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the logitech z906, but it seems to have good reviews, so it looks like it's a very capable full-range speaker system.

As you haven't identified a particular problem with them, I would suggest they are likely to be perfectly good for monitoring while playing your keyboard.

If you were to get a good pair of monitors, with a good amplifier, and site them and mount them properly in an acoustically-suitable environment, then you might find they had "better quality" than your Logitech in some way - such as a flatter response, for example. But that wouldn't necessarily make them any more enjoyable to play through.

A good keyboard amplifier will obviously be more portable and will probably let you play a lot louder than the Logitech system without distortion - but at home, you don't need anything portable, and there are presumably limits on how loud you can play anyway?

To quote Billy Joel,

> Don't waste your money on a new set of speakers
>   You get more mileage from a cheap pair of sneakers
>   Next phase, new wave, dance craze, anyways 
>   It's still rock and roll to me